# Laravel Cant save image using Storage

Tags: php, image, laravel, storage

I cant save a image using the storage method.

If I do: `$file->move(public_path().'/', $file->getClientOriginalName());`

The image will get saved and I can open it in finder.

But if I save the image using:

```
$extension = $file->guessExtension();
      $filename = 'thumnail_'.$id.'.'.$extension;
      if ($file) {
          $s3 = Storage::disk('public')->put($filename, $file);
      }
```

It will also get saved to the folder but then I cant open it because the file is corrupted

And to be clear "file" is sent to my model from a controller: $file = $request->file('images');

Comment: $filename has to have a path..

Comment: What is the public disk configuration for your filesystem? I did some tests here with the default values and it works smoothly. If you're using s3 to store files you'll have to install a package for that. All about it in: https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/filesystem.

Comment: Based on documentation, $file must be content of file, you can use file_get_contents, so :

    if ($file) {
          $s3 = Storage::disk('public')->put($filename, file_get_contents($file));
    }

Comment: @YohananBaruchel what are you talking about? I am writing ('public') which stores at the /storage folder. The file gets saved I only cant open it

Comment: @MokhamadRofi'udin but doesnt ```$request->file('images');``` take care of that?

Comment: It is set to store in /app. I want to save the file on my system first, then start a queue which will resize/upload the file to S3. Only problem is that I cant pass a file directly from form to a queue and I have to save it on my system first so the queue can read it

Comment: @user2722667 
First, the $request->file(...); result is Illuminate/Http/UploadedFile.php
You can directly save to storage with : `$request->file(...)->storeAs($path, $filename, $diskname);` check
[https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.3/src/Illuminate/Http/UploadedFile.php#L60] 
it use `putFileAs` to handle that. 
Then see this code [https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.3/src/Illuminate/Filesystem/FilesystemAdapter.php#L119] 
it read the file then put the content in put method.